# Fiber pool crashes hard when using thin

Tags: ruby, thin

When I try to launch my rails project using `rails server thin` it starts up just fine but when I request any page I get:

```
$ rails server thin
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/fiber_pool.rb:75: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0028 p:---- s:0109 b:0109 l:000108 d:000108 CFUNC  :resume
c:0027 p:0067 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/fiber_pool.rb:75
c:0026 p:0026 s:0100 b:0100 l:000d38 d:000d38 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/rack/fiber_pool.rb:28
c:0025 p:0015 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16
c:0024 p:0015 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0023 p:0020 s:0081 b:0081 l:000072 d:000080 BLOCK  /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84
c:0022 p:---- s:0079 b:0079 l:000078 d:000078 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 CFUNC  :catch
c:0020 p:0135 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82
c:0019 p:0088 s:0068 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57
c:0018 p:0036 s:0064 b:0064 l:000063 d:000063 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42
c:0017 p:---- s:0059 b:0059 l:000058 d:000058 FINISH
c:0016 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 CFUNC  :run_machine
c:0015 p:0325 s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/eventmachine-86784d267448/lib/eventmachine.rb:186
c:0014 p:0066 s:0047 b:0047 l:001ee0 d:001ee0 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61
c:0013 p:0143 s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159
c:0012 p:0081 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13
c:0011 p:0269 s:0034 b:0034 l:002608 d:002608 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:265
c:0010 p:0231 s:0029 b:0029 l:001ed0 d:001ed0 METHOD /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70
c:0009 p:0063 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0721 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0000f8 d:0022a8 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0000f8 d:0000f8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in '
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/eventmachine-86784d267448/lib/eventmachine.rb:186:in `run'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/eventmachine-86784d267448/lib/eventmachine.rb:186:in `run_machine'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `pre_process'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `catch'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `block in pre_process'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/rack/fiber_pool.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/fiber_pool.rb:75:in `spawn'
/Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-fiber_pool-0.9.2/lib/fiber_pool.rb:75:in `resume'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010381964e rb_vm_bugreport + 110
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010370d4b3 report_bug + 259
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010370d621 rb_bug + 161
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001037b00c2 sigbus + 18
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff96a97cfa _sigtramp + 26
5   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[1]    16265 abort      rails server thin
```

Here's my `gem env` output

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/nicklas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /Users/nicklas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

And `gem list`

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
addressable (2.2.6)
api_smith (1.0.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
capybara (1.1.1)
childprocess (0.2.2)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
columnize (0.3.4)
cookiejar (0.3.0)
daemons (1.1.4)
dalli (1.1.3)
date_validator (0.6.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
ejs (1.0.0)
em-socksify (0.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
exceptional (2.0.32)
execjs (1.2.9)
factory_girl (2.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (1.3.0)
faraday (0.7.5)
ffi (1.0.9)
fssm (0.2.7)
gabba (0.1.1)
guard (0.8.8)
guard-rspec (0.5.2)
haml (3.1.3)
handlebars_assets (0.1.3)
hashie (1.2.0)
hike (1.2.1)
http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
httparty (0.8.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.16)
json (1.6.1)
json_pure (1.6.1)
launchy (2.0.5)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.3.0)
maruku (0.6.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.3)
multi_xml (0.4.1)
multipart-post (1.1.3)
newrelic_rpm (3.1.2)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
oauth2 (0.5.1)
omniauth (1.0.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
pg (0.11.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pony (1.3)
rack (1.3.5)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-fiber_pool (0.9.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.1)
rails-backbone (0.5.4)
railties (3.1.1)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.11)
remote_syslog_logger (1.0.3)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.7.0)
rspec-core (2.7.1)
rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
rspec-rails (2.7.0)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sass (3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.10.0)
simple-navigation (3.5.0)
simple_form (1.5.2)
sprockets (2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
syntax (1.0.0)
syslog_protocol (0.9.1)
thin (1.2.11)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.0.4)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

---

### Update 1

I've now reinstalled my computer (upgrade of HDD) and I still see the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I use 1.9.3 but only if it's compiled using `--with-gcc=clang`, I'll be using this until they fix 1.9.2

Comment: Thx for sharing, installing 1.9.3 with clang worked for me. Is there any other solution yet?

Comment: Actually, I've stopped using fiber pool so I don't know.